# Test class for Wrapper Class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have tried this but getting an this  Error Message System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
Stack Trace Class.Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.: line 72, column 1
Class.TestHos_Vol_MultiAdd.validateHos_Vol_MultiAdd: line 27, column 1

Please help me for code coverage.

**Apex Class :**

```
public with sharing class Hos_Vol_MultiAdd {
  public Account acc{get;set;}
  //will hold the Hospitals-Volunteers records to be saved
  public List<Hospitals_Volunteers__c>lstAcct  = new List<Hospitals_Volunteers__c>();

  //list of the inner class
  public List<innerClass> lstInner { get; set; }

  //will indicate the row to be deleted
  public String selectedRowIndex { get; set; }  

  //no. of rows added/records in the inner class list
  public Integer count = 1;

  public PageReference Cancel() {
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+acc.id);
    pr.setRedirect(True);
    return pr;
  } 

  //save the records by adding the elements in the inner class list to lstAcct,return to the same page
  public PageReference Save() {
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('/'+acc.id);
    for(Integer j = 0;j<lstInner.size();j++) {
      lstAcct.add(lstInner[j].acct);
    } 
    insert lstAcct;
    pr.setRedirect(True);
    return pr;
  } 

  //add one more row
  public void Add() {   
    count = count+1;
    addMore();      
  }

  /*Begin addMore*/
  public void addMore() {
    //call to the iner class constructor
    innerClass objInnerClass = new innerClass(count, acc);
    //add the record to the inner class list
    lstInner.add(objInnerClass);    
    system.debug('lstInner---->'+lstInner);            
  }/* end addMore*/

  /* begin delete */
  public void Del() {
    system.debug('selected row index---->'+selectedRowIndex);
    lstInner.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedRowIndex)-1);
    count = count - 1;
  }/*End del*/

  /*Constructor*/
  public Hos_Vol_MultiAdd(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    String hosId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('accid');
    acc = [Select id, Name from Account where id =: hosId];
    lstInner = new List<innerClass>();
    addMore();
    selectedRowIndex = '0';
  }
  /*End Constructor*/

  /*Inner Class*/
  public class innerClass {       
    /*recCount acts as a index for a row. This will be helpful to identify the row to be deleted */
    public String recCount { get; set; }
    public Hospitals_Volunteers__c acct { get; set; }
    /*Inner Class Constructor*/
    public innerClass(Integer intCount, Account acc) {
      recCount = String.valueOf(intCount);        
      acct = new Hospitals_Volunteers__c(Hospital_Name__c= acc.id);
    }/*End Inner class Constructor*/    
  }/*End inner Class*/
}/*End Class*/
```

**Test Class :**

```
 @isTest
private class TestHos_Vol_MultiAdd {
 static testMethod void validateHos_Vol_MultiAdd() {
    account a = new account();
   a.name = 'NIMS';
   a.BillingStreet = 'Marathahalli';
   a.BillingCity = 'Bangalore';
   a.BillingState = 'Karnataka';
   a.BillingPostalCode = '560037';
   a.BillingCountry = 'India';
   insert a;

    volunteer__c v = new volunteer__c();
    v.name = 'Raj';

  insert v;

  Hospitals_Volunteers__c hos=new Hospitals_Volunteers__c();
  hos.Volunteer__c=v.id;
  hos.Hospital_Name__c=a.id;
  insert hos;

Integer count = 1;
ApexPages.StandardController hosvolcon= new ApexPages.standardController(a);
apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().put('id','a.id');
Hos_Vol_MultiAdd hosvol= new Hos_Vol_MultiAdd(hosvolcon);
Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.innerClass ho=new Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.innerClass(1,a);
hosvol.addMore();
hosvol.Cancel();
hosvol.add();
hosvol.save();
hosvol.del();

 }

}
```

Comment: use `@TestVisible` annotation for your inner class

Comment: still getting same error :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you define your constructor with 2 parameters:

```
public innerClass(Integer intCount, Account acc)
```

and then try to create a new *innerClass* without any parameters:

```
Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.innerclass  mi = new Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.innerclass();
```

Instead you should create a new instance of *innerClass* with those 2 parameters declared in the constructor, so it will look something like:

```
Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.innerclass  mi = new Hos_Vol_MultiAdd.innerclass(1, a); //change '1' and 'a' if you need to, just make sure they are of type Integer and Account
```

Comment: Could you write 100% coverage for this wrapper class, please?

Comment: @Vivek I could, but you should learn it. There will not always be a person to write a test class for you, so learn it yourself or hire developers to do it for you(the first option is a bit cheaper)

Comment: Novarg ,Thanks for your valuable words. you are absolutely right  but who will teach me? I referred so many links i did not understand.

Comment: @Vivek http://bit.ly/1AfZnVN

Comment: thank you :) I know how to write test class but am writing first time test class for wrapper class. that is problem . Help me vivek.pellakuru@gmail.com

Answer (score -1):

You would also need to fulfil the requirement of the constructor for the controller Hol_Vol_MultiAdd. It requires an instance of a standard controller.

```
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(your sobject here);
```

And then pass it when you instantiate the controller

```
Hos_Vol_MultiAdd controller = new Hos_Vol_MultiAdd(sc);
```

Comment: Could you write 100% coverage for this wrapper class, please?

Comment: I think we've answered your question. You just need to implement the solutions into your test class. You also have resources here https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_test.htm .

Comment: thank you but am new to this wrapper class, understand the situation.